# crash on NSString stringWithFormat

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a line code that creates a NSString like below,

```
NSString *paramString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?user_id=%@&x=%@&y=%@",_selectedID, _selectedX,[MyModel shared].currentUser.userID];
```

I do get crash report as below :

```
crash in :
Thread 0 crashed:
libobjc.dylib      objc_msgSend + 16
CoreFoundation _NSDescriptionWithLocaleFunc + 68
CoreFoundation _CFStringAppendFormatCore + 6004
CoreFoundation _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux + 116
Foundation [NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments] + 160
```

`userID` in currentUser is a NSString.
`_selectdID` and `_selectedX` are both NSStrings passed from VC1 --> VC2 ---> VC3. In VC2 and VC3, both are declared as `@property(nonatomic,assign)`.

However this crash only occurs for around 1% of users and all of them are on iOS 7.1.1 as per crash report.

I tried to simulate it with no luck. Is it because of memory is released ? Is there any to simulate this?

Comment: It's likely because `_selectedID` or `_selectedX` have already been deallocated when you are creating your string.  Why do you have them declared as `assign`?  You should declare them as `strong` so they don't get deallocated when you are still using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare your NSString properties with copy or strong modifiers in order to ensure they are in memory. They can be deallocated and their pointers make reference to another var

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it is being dereferenced afterwards .Please use the keyword `strong` so that it is not being dereferenced.